# Cannot hide dropdown border in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

I am trying to hide the border of a dropdown box. The border is correctly hidden in browsers like Chrome and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer the border is still appearing.

Here is my css to hide the border:

```css
.gf-menu .dropdown ul li .item {
    border: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

How do I hide the border in Internet Explorer as well as other browsers.

Comment: seems to work fine for me, which version of ie are you using?

Comment: I checked the issue and its is getting reflected in IE9. I did a `border:none;` and it resolves OP's issue. - @Pete

Answer (score 1):

Try `border:none;`

**For Instance,**

```
.gf-menu .dropdown ul li .item {
  border: none;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack for IE specific CSS

```
.gf-menu .dropdown ul li .item{  
 border: none; /* all browsers, of course */  
 border: none\9; /* IE8 and below */  
 *border: none; /* IE7 and below */  
 _border: none; /* IE6 */  
}
```

Comment: Why you need a hack? If all values are the same? Is useless

Comment: Sometimes some properties are not supported by the old version especially by IE. So you need some hacks.

Comment: Not for `border` and when properties aren't supported you use other values and properties not define the same with the hacks they are not like prefixe vendors.

Comment: Ok – now the site (www.te1.dk/test) is with "border: none;" and that fixes the border problem. But now menu text starts to jump. Not much, but it’s jumping…

Comment: @JonasHansen You have to try the same for :hover class around LOC 2396 of your css

Comment: @ ITConflux: Inserted “#rt-top-surround a:hover { border: none;}” – didn’t do the trick. Menu still jumping.

Comment: There is padding-top:1px in :hover class around line 577 which is causing the jump effect... Hope this will help

Comment: @ ITConflux: That fixed the problem Thanx a lot.

How do I mark my question as solved?

Comment: Sorry for being late here is the link which may solve your issue
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved